# Is $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=c^2$ possible?

Tags: average, square-numbers

I am looking for an integer solution to the equation:
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=c^2(a\neq b\neq c)$$
That is a square number that is the mean of two other square numbers, is this possible? And if so please can you give me an example?

Comment: How about $a=b=c=2$?

Comment: @Uncountable sorry I meant to say that they all have to be different.

Comment: In that case, $a=7$, $b=1$ and $c=5$ will work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We know that $(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2=2(x^2+y^2).$

So, if $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$, then $c^2=x^2+y^2.$

Now see [Formulas for generating Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples).

Answer (score 0):

for example;a=1,b=7,c=5 or a=2,b=14,c=10

Answer (score 0):

This means $a^2,c^2,b^2$ are in arithmetic progression. Without loss of generality assuming $a,b,c$ are mutually relatively prime, we have that
$$a = p-q, b=p+q \text{ and }c = r$$
where $p$,$q$ and $r$ form Pythagorean triplets. In fact, all such squares in arithmetic progression must necessarily be of the form.

[A detailed characterization is presented here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve3zvdb6yxy75xn/Squares_In_AP.pdf?dl=0)

[Also, as an aside no four squares can be in arithmetic progression.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjj6g9a5xnr0kae/Four_Squares_In_AP.pdf?dl=0)